# Compare User Entered Character x86_64 Assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64

I am trying to compare a user entered character (A - E) and run a specific label if they are equal. However, it does not seem to be comparing correctly, and is running my default fail label. It gets the input successfully, but it seems the `cmp` is not working correctly. Below is my code:

```
section .data
    ; constants
    NULL        equ 0
    EXIT_SUCCESS    equ 0
    EXIT_FAIL   equ 1
    SYS_exit    equ 60
    SYS_read    equ 0
    SYS_write   equ 1
    STD_in      equ 0
    STD_out     equ 1
    lA      equ "A"
    lB      equ "B"
    lC      equ "C"
    lD      equ "D"
    lE      equ "E"
    
    ; other
    text1   db "Please enter an upper-case letter from A-E: "
    errmsg  db "Error: incorrect letter chosen."
    sucmsg  db "Success."

section .bss
    ; reserve space for user input
    letter resb 1

section .text
    global _start
    
_start: 
    
    ; print question
    ; sys_write (1, text, 43)
    mov rax, SYS_write
    mov rdi, STD_out
    mov rsi, text1
    mov rdx, 43
    syscall
    
    ; get user input
    ; sys_read (0, letter, 1)
    mov rax, SYS_read
    mov rdi, STD_in
    mov rsi, letter
    mov rdx, 1
    syscall
    
    ; jump conditionals
    mov rdx, lA
    cmp rsi, rdx
    je _printA
    
    mov rdx, lB
    cmp rsi, rdx
    je _printB
    
    mov rdx, lC
    cmp rsi, rdx
    je _printC
    
    mov rdx, lD
    cmp rsi, rdx
    je _printD
    
    mov rdx, lE
    cmp rsi, rdx
    je _printE
    
    ; default jump if no match
    jmp _exitFail
    
_printA:
    ; sys_write (1, text, 1)
    mov rax, SYS_write
    mov rdi, STD_out
    ; mov rsi, "A"
    mov rdx, 1
    syscall
    
    jmp _exitSuccess

_printB:    
    ; sys_write (1, text, 1)
    mov rax, SYS_write
    mov rdi, STD_out
    ; mov rsi, "B"
    mov rdx, 1
    syscall
    
    jmp _exitSuccess
    
_printC:
    ; sys_write (1, text, 1)
    mov rax, SYS_write
    mov rdi, STD_out
    ; mov rsi, "C"
    mov rdx, 1
    syscall
    
    jmp _exitSuccess

_printD:
    ; sys_write (1, text, 1)
    mov rax, SYS_write
    mov rdi, STD_out
    ; mov rsi, "D"
    mov rdx, 1
    syscall
    
    jmp _exitSuccess

_printE:
    ; sys_write (1, text, 1)
    mov rax, SYS_write
    mov rdi, STD_out
    ; mov rsi, "E"
    mov rdx, 1
    syscall
    
    jmp _exitSuccess
    
_exitSuccess:
    ; print success msg
    ; sys_write (1, errmsg, 8)
    mov rax, SYS_write
    mov rdi, STD_out
    mov rsi, sucmsg
    mov rdx, 8
    syscall
    
    ; sys_exit (0)
    mov rax, SYS_exit
    mov rdi, EXIT_SUCCESS
    syscall
    
_exitFail:
    ; print fail msg
    ; sys_write (1, errmsg, 31)
    mov rax, SYS_write
    mov rdi, STD_out
    mov rsi, errmsg
    mov rdx, 31
    syscall
    
    ; sys_exit (1)
    mov rax, SYS_exit
    mov rdi, EXIT_FAIL
    syscall
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before `syscall SYS_read` you have correctly loaded RSI with address of `letter`.
At the `; jump conditionals` you compare the **letters** in RDX with **address** of `letter`, which remains in RSI.
Dereference RSI prior to *jump conditionals* with `MOVZX RSI,[byte letter]`.

Or simply use

```
CMP  byte [byte letter],'A'
JE   _printA
CMP  byte [byte letter],'B'
JE   _printB
... etc
```

Or, if you want to avoid jumps (for performace reason), make an **array** of QWORD pointers to `_printA`, `_printB` etc in `SECTION .data`, convert the obtained letter **A, B, C, D, E**  to numeric index **0, 1, 2, 3, 4** in RSI and instead of  *jump conditionals* use one jump `JMP [qword array+8*RSI]`.

Comment: Thank you, sir. All makes sense. I am not yet to the point of creating an array, but will try implement in the future.

Comment: @Dean An array in assembly is a collection of items of the same size, one after another: `array dq _printA, _printB, _printC, _printD, _printE`.